# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

Tags: java

Help me to solve this error. This code is for Gutherine series.Consider the following algorithm
    Start with a positive number n
    if n is even then divide by 2
    if n is odd then multiply by 3 and add 1
    continue this until n becomes 1

```
   public class Gutherine {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[] = {8, 3,2, 1};
        int result = isGutherineSequence(a);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public static int isGutherineSequence(int a[]) {
        int i = 0;
        int t = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (a[i] % 2 == 0) {
                if (a[i + 1] == a[i] / 2) {
                    t++;
                }
            } else if (a[i + 1] == a[i] * 3 + 1) {
                t++;
            }
        }
        if (t == 3) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Since inside your loop you access `a[i+1]`, you should iterate `i` until the next to last element, so change

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
```

to

```
for (i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++)
```

BTW, you don't need the `t` counter. Once you discover that the series is not a `Gutherine` sequence, you can return false. You also fail to check that the last element is 1. And you should return a boolean instead of 0 or 1.

Here's a suggested implementation :

```
public static boolean isGutherineSequence(int a[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
        if (a[i] % 2 == 0) {
            if (a[i + 1] != a[i] / 2) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (a[i + 1] != a[i] * 3 + 1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return (a[a.length - 1] == 1);
}
```

Comment: would only solve the problem if it's ok to not touch the rightmost array element during the run of the loop.  That doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: @La-comadreja The right-most array element is examined in the last iteration of the loop when you access `a[i+1]`.

Answer (score 1):

The exception is caused by your referring to

```
a[i + 1]
```

If a[i] could be any element of the array, a[i + 1] could be one to the right of the rightmost element.  So your array index would be out of bounds in that case.

Answer (score 0):

The out-of-bounds exception results from your the indirection `a[i + 1]` even when `i` is odd. The loop in your `isGutherineSequence` function will let `i` reach 3 and the offending line

```
} else if (a[i + 1] == a[i] * 3 + 1) {
```

Will effectively try to extract a non-existent `a[4]`.

You should either stop the loop at a previous spot or provide an alternate test for the last element.